# GlassFish Connection Pool to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, odbc, glassfish-3

For my sins I have to make the web application I'm working on interact with an old MS Access database that is used by one of our legacy applications.

The first problem with Access of course is how to get a connection. After extensive searching I wasn't able to find any type 3 or 4 driver that I was happy with (everyone that sells them seems to have stopped development years ago) so that has pushed me into using the JDBC-ODBC bridge.

As I've not used the bridge for over a decade I banged out a quick bit of code to check everything was working:

```
sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource ds = new sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource();
ds.setDatabaseName("MyDatabase");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement( "SELECT * FROM MyTable" );
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while( rs.next() ) {
    System.out.println( rs.getString( 1 ) );
}
```

I decided to use the `DataSource` as this is closer to how it'll be used in the final application. The above code runs fine and gives the expected result.

I then set up a JDBC Connection Pool under GlassFish 3.1.1. I set Resource Type to `javax.sql.DataSource` and gave the Datasource Classname as `sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource`. I also set a single property of databaseName=MyDatabase.

When I ping the database through GlassFish I get this error message:

```
Ping Connection Pool for MyConnectionPool is Failed. Ping failed 
Exception - Connection could not be allocated because: 
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] System resource exceeded.
```

The system.log for GlassFish doesn't really provide any more information it just reports:

```
Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ MyConnectionPool ]
```

and then repeats the error message. I've tried changing the pool parameters in GlassFish thinking that it might be an issue with how many connections it's trying to pool but that didn't work. Any ideas?

P.S. Moving to MS SQL / MySQL / Other DB is not currently and option :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what was actually wrong, turning off auto-ping on changes and restarting the system caused it to start working and I've not had any problems since.